# If somebody dies in my house, should I plan to be staying at a hotel?

Tags: united-states, death

In the event that somebody dies at my house, is it going to turn into a crime scene? I am thinking here of situations like George Michael's death, where somebody just dies, but there is no obvious cause of death, so obviously the police have latitude to decide whether it is a "suspicious" or "non-suspicious" death. Since there is no coroner's report, they have no way to know whether it is natural causes or not.

So, my concern is that my house turns into a big evidence collection nightmare, does that mean I have to leave and stay in a hotel while they are "documenting" the scene? How long will that take?

Comment: I imagine that this is decided on a case by case basis. Also, what country?

Comment: @Thunderforge I know it is. I am asking whether I need to move out if they decide to collect evidence. Did you even read the question?

Comment: @K-C I don't care what the investigators say, I want a QUALIFIED legal opinion about how to handle a situation like this by either (1) a cop who does death investigations, (2) an experienced criminal attorney, or (3) somebody who otherwise has significant experience with these situations.

Comment: @Cicero if you want a QUALIFIED legal opinion, you will need to pay a lawyer for it

Comment: If someone dies at your house and the police finds out you had booked a hotel room before the person died, I would guess you will not need the hotel room since you will spend the night at an interrogation room...

Comment: @DaleM The Help page for this site says the following: "Law Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for legal professionals,..." So, I think I it is within reason for me to expect a professional opinion here.

Comment: You *might* get an answer from a legal professional, but it [*won't* be a professional opinion](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-advice), and I can count the number of existing users who *admit* their professional credentials on my fingers (and yes, I only have ten).  You should be grateful for *any helpful answers* you receive on any Stack Exchange.

Comment: @feetwet Well, so far I have not got any helpful answers, just a lot of guesses and random remarks.

Answer (score 1):

Police are required to "secure" evidence of a crime.  They can remove you from a crime scene if they consider that necessary to secure it.  They will subsequently obtain a warrant to search the scene.  Once it starts that search can go on for as long as they want, unless you can convince a judge that they are behaving unreasonably.

(I hope to return to add citations to this when I have more time.)